# rating component with custom icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-reuse

I am striving to make customized rating component. I know there are other libraries for it but I wanted to do it myself so i can understand the underlying process. However, i am struggling on custom component part. For default case, it's working fine. For custom component what I tried is allow developer to pass svg component of their desired icon and then show that icon as a rating component. Up to this, it's working but I have no idea on handling mouseover, mouseout functionality.

here is what I have tried

```
import React from "react";

const DefaultComponent = ({
  ratingRef,
  currentRating,
  handleMouseOut,
  handleMouseOver,
  handleStarClick,
  totalRating
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="rating"
      ref={ratingRef}
      data-rating={currentRating}
      onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
    >
      {[...Array(+totalRating).keys()].map(n => {
        return (
          <span
            className="star"
            key={n + 1}
            data-value={n + 1}
            onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
            onClick={handleStarClick}
          >
            &#9733;
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const CustomComponent = ({
  ratingRef,
  currentRating,
  handleMouseOut,
  handleMouseOver,
  handleStarClick,
  totalRating,
  ratingComponent
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {[...Array(+totalRating).keys()].map(n => {
        return ratingComponent({ key: n });
      })}
    </>
  );
};

const Rating = props => {
  const { totalRating = 5, onClick, ratingComponent } = props;
  const [currentRating, setCurrentRating] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleMouseOut();
  }, []);
  const handleMouseOver = ev => {
    const stars = ev.target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("star");
    const hoverValue = ev.target.dataset.value;
    Array.from(stars).forEach(star => {
      star.style.color = hoverValue >= star.dataset.value ? "#FDC60A" : "#444";
    });
  };

  const handleMouseOut = ev => {
    const stars = ratingRef?.current?.getElementsByClassName("star");
    stars &&
      Array.from(stars).forEach(star => {
        star.style.color =
          currentRating >= star.dataset.value ? "#FDC60A" : "#444";
      });
  };

  const handleStarClick = ev => {
    let rating = ev.target.dataset.value;
    setCurrentRating(rating); // set state so the rating stays highlighted
    if (onClick) {
      onClick(rating); // emit the event up to the parent
    }
  };

  const ratingRef = React.useRef();
  console.log("ratingComponent", ratingComponent);
  return (
    <>
      {ratingComponent ? (
        <CustomComponent
          ratingRef={ratingRef}
          currentRating={currentRating}
          handleMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
          handleMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
          handleStarClick={handleStarClick}
          totalRating={totalRating}
          ratingComponent={ratingComponent}
        />
      ) : (
        <DefaultComponent
          ratingRef={ratingRef}
          currentRating={currentRating}
          handleMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
          handleMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
          handleStarClick={handleStarClick}
          totalRating={totalRating}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Rating;
```

I have created a sandbox as well.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-almeida-yz7ju?file=/src/components/Rating/Rating.js:0-2731

Can anyone give me idea on how to make reusable rating component which can support custom icons for rating like in my case i needed exactly that gem and star icon?

Comment: what's you intent? you want to customize it to be able to handle different svgs other than the star?

Comment: i want it to support custom icons as well. If custom icon is provided then it should be shown for rating otherwise a default one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

- reuse your `DefaultComponent` to take in the icon
- use classnames instead of selecting DOM elements; one for default and one for hover. Add `fill` or `color` properties for the hover/selected classname
- use a `hoverIndex` state to track which element I'm hovering on
- Improvement: colocate the hover events within the `DefaultComponent` since the are relevant to only the icon, and aren't needed in the parent container

I had trouble styling the `star` svg. Essentially, you need to override the `fill` color for it - but it seems to be a complicated one. If you can simplify it, or pass down the fill as `prop` into the svg and use it internally - either would work!

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-pascal-j1d0c

Hope this helps!

```js
const DefaultIcon = _ => "a"; //  = '&#9733'

const DefaultComponent = ({
  ratingComponent = DefaultIcon,
  ratingRef,
  currentRating,
  handleStarClick,
  totalRating
}) => {
  const RatingIconComponent = ratingComponent;

  const [hoverIndex, setHoverIndex] = React.useState(-Infinity);

  const handleMouseOver = index => {
    setHoverIndex(index);
  };

  const handleMouseOut = ev => {
    setHoverIndex(-Infinity);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="rating"
      ref={ratingRef}
      data-rating={currentRating}
      onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
    >
      {[...Array(+totalRating).keys()].map(n => {
        const isFilled = n < currentRating || n <= hoverIndex;

        return (
          <span
            className={`ratingIcon ${isFilled && "fill"}`}
            key={n + 1}
            data-value={n + 1}
            onMouseOver={_ => handleMouseOver(n)}
            onClick={_ => handleStarClick(n + 1)}
          >
            <RatingIconComponent />
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const Rating = props => {
  const { totalRating = 5, onClick, ratingComponent } = props;
  const [currentRating, setCurrentRating] = React.useState(0);

  const handleStarClick = rating => {
    setCurrentRating(rating); // set state so the rating stays highlighted
    if (onClick) {
      onClick(rating); // emit the event up to the parent
    }
  };

  const ratingRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <DefaultComponent
      ratingComponent={ratingComponent}
      ratingRef={ratingRef}
      currentRating={currentRating}
      handleStarClick={handleStarClick}
      totalRating={totalRating}
    />
  );
};
```

```
<Rating ratingComponent={Gem} />
```

```css
/* for normal text */
.ratingIcon {
  color: "gray";
}

.ratingIcon.fill {
  color: yellow;
}

/* for svg */
.ratingIcon svg path {
  fill: gray !important;
}

.ratingIcon.fill svg path {
  fill: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and solution. Yeah the main problem is overriding the fill color. Initially, i tried to override fill property but in the case of star svg the fill property of polygon has to be overriden. It seemed like it's different for different icons.

Comment: we usually clean up the `svg` before such using it, so you could try to remove/alter stuff to make it simpler.

Comment: sorry did not understand 'we usually clean up the svg'. Can you explain this a bit, please?

Comment: I have not tried yet but i think masking svg will work.